# ListView item Content save in the Variable to identify table or column in SQlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I was wondering to get Content of the Current Item of List and save it in the Variable when user will Click on it.

i.e List is showing three items. 1. Android 2. Iphone 3. Nokia

When user will click on any item, say clicked on iphone. in the onItemClick function. get the data "iphone" and save it to variable. So that we can use it for Table or Column identification.

If there is any way than please mention it, Any function/Method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view you clicked is passed into the onItemClick() method in the OnItemClickListener.

```
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // handle event here...
        }
    }
```

You can get anything off of the view you want.  If you just want the text, you can do something like this:

```
String myText = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view)).getText();
```

Comment: Perfect... I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (assuming "phones" would be the id of your list adapter):

```
    phones.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            String phone = phones.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, THanks. yes I have done exactly same thing :) By the way what onNothingSelected will do. I haven't used that.

Comment: I don't actually know... I grabbed that code from some stuff I was playing around with while teaching myself a few months ago and I don't think I ever tried to use it (it was in an example I copied from).  I don't actually know how it would get fired as it seems the list/spinner come up with the first item selected no matter what,